# The SharePoint 2010 Logo, high-res version

Tags: recommendations

For publicity purposes I need the SharePoint 2010 logo in a high resolution. Does anyone know where i can get it?

I already tried

- http://www.microsoft.com/Presspass/gallery/ms-logos.mspx (No SharePoint logos at all)
- http://www.brandsoftheworld.com (only 2007 version)

Answer (score 3):

Also - SharePoint 2010: SharePoint Developer Platform Wall Poster.  I found it great!

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04BA41FD-F088-4D7C-A86E-3855C16E23A2&displaylang=en&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these are good enough for you, but hope they help.

[Office 2010 Icons](http://blog.taragana.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/office.jpg)

[SharePoint 2010 Wheel](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/sharepoint/WindowsLiveWriter/SharePoint2010%5F13F16/image1.png)

[My SkyDrive](http://cid-add724703261f514.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public)

Comment: Thanks! It is a start. I need them to be usable in print and those aren't just big enough (if i believe my printer/publisher).

Answer (score 2):

How about these posters:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199%28office.14%29.aspx

Thanks,
Kamlesh

Comment: Nice posters, none of them contains the SharePoint 2010 logo.